# Accessing iFrames with Phantomjs Watir

Tags: javascript, ruby, iframe, phantomjs, watir

My script is trying to access this login page:

http://instagram.com/accounts/login

with PhantomJS, Watir.

The problem with the login page is that the login textfields are in an iFrame:

```
<iframe class="hiFrame" data-reactid=".0.0.0.1.0.1.0.0.$frame" src="https://instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/?targetOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Finstagram.com" scrolling="no" seamless="">
  #document
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html class="hl-en not-logged-in " lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head></head>
    <body class="LoginFormChrome ">
      <div class="LoginFormPage" data-reactid=".0">
        <form data-reactid=".0.0">
          <p class="lfField" data-reactid=".0.0.0">
            <label class="lfFieldLabel" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0"></label>
            <input class="lfFieldInput" type="text" data-reactid=".0.0.0.1" value="" autocorrect="false" autocapitalize="false" maxlength="30" name="username"></input>
          </p>
          <p class="lfField" data-reactid=".0.0.1"></p>
          <p class="lfActions" data-reactid=".0.0.2"></p>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="fb-root" class=" fb_reset"></div>
    </body>
  </html>
</iframe>
```

Here's my code (Ruby):

```
B.goto HOME_URL + LOGIN
sleep(5)            
puts B.iframe(:class => "hiFrame").text_field(:name => "username").exists?
B.iframe(:class => "hiFrame").text_field(:name => "username").set USERNAME
B.iframe(:class => "hiFrame").text_field(:name => "password").set PW
#puts B.iframe(:class => "hiFrame").text_field(:name => "username").exists?
B.iframe(:class => "hiFrame").button.click
```

Works perfectly fine using the Firefox browser, but when I switch to Phantomjs, it doesn't recognize

```
B.iframe(:class => "hiFrame").text_field(:name => "username").exists?
```

and stops the script. Returns "true" for:

```
B.iframe(:class => "hiFrame").exists?
```

But that's the extent of it. How can I login to instagram with phantomjs and watir?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the frame is showing the Facebook cross-domain messenger helper. You might need to look into whether PhantomJS supports cross-domain iframes or not.

Comment: What happens if PhantomJS doesn't? Are there any alternatives to access iframes headlessly?

Comment: You could try the [headless gem](http://watirwebdriver.com/headless/). I have not used it, so do not know what its limitations are.

Comment: Hi Justin, I tried looking for whether PhantomJS supports cross-domain frames and I couldn't find anything... I only found this. Control web security

Performing cross-domain XHR is often necessary for some scripting purposes. This is now possible by disabling web security (issue 28), either with --web-security=no command-line option or webSecurityEnabled page setting.

Comment: If I were to run my script remotely would it still work?

Comment: Remotely as in running an actual browser such as Firefox on another machine? Yes that would also work.

Comment: On another machine envirnoment such as iron.io with ironworker.

Comment: @justin I disabled crossdomain security but I'm still not able to access the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your code before you go the page:

```
B = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
B.window.resize_to(800, 600)
```

If you set a window size it should work. Phantomjs needs to be specified a browser size typically.

```
B.window.resize_to(800, 600)
B.goto HOME_URL + LOGIN
sleep(5)            
puts B.iframe(:class => "hiFrame").text_field(:name => "username").exists?
B.iframe(:class => "hiFrame").text_field(:name => "username").set USERNAME
B.iframe(:class => "hiFrame").text_field(:name => "password").set PW
#puts B.iframe(:class => "hiFrame").text_field(:name => "username").exists?
B.iframe(:class => "hiFrame").button.click
```